# Naming PDFs downloaded using python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, pdf

I have a webscraper for work that downloads all pdfs for given filters from our non-public website. I'm trying to name the files *"ID Number + File name + date file was made.pdf"* I used the absolute `xPath` for the File name in a Try statement, but its not working and jumping to the exception. I would appreciate a second set of eyes to see if I have missed anything syntax-wise, or if there's a better way to implement this. I have also copied the `xPath` as well to see if anyone with more experience can give me the relative `xPath` to use

**Error**:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/h2"}
  (Session info: chrome=93.0.4577.63)
```

**HTML**:

[image]

**My code:**

```
table_rows=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, '#resources/details/?id=')]")
    for link_elem in table_rows:
        url = link_elem.get_attribute('href')
        id_number= url[-8:]
        driver.get(url)
       try:
            filename_first = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/h2').text.replace(':', '').replace(r'/', '-')

       except:
            filename_first = 'file.pdf'
        #filename_first = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/h2').text.replace(':', '').replace(r'/', '-')
        filename_final = id_number + filename_first #+ '.pdf'
        css_thing =  '#file > div:nth-child(1) > div.form-group.padding-xs-bottom > div > div > button.btn.btn-danger.get-download-url'
        time.sleep(5)
        download_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(css_thing)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, css_thing))).click()
        time.sleep(5)
        link_data = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'https://s3.amazonaws.com')]")
        url = link_data.get_attribute("href")
        r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
        open(filename_final, 'wb').write(r.content)
        print("good")
```

Comment: You shouldn't use these type of dynamic xpath `/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/h2`

Comment: Try this `//a//div[@class='flex-1 ellipsis padding-xs-right']`

Comment: @NandanA Thanlks! Now when I run  filename_first = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a//div[@class='flex-1 ellipsis padding-xs-right']").text.replace(':', '').replace(r'/', '-') + '.pdf' The file name becomes just .pdf

Comment: Can you give us sample pdf name to see

Comment: @NandanA Sure! currently with that line of code the name is just .pdf. and then as it iterates the loop it just writes over that file. when i remove + '.pdf' from the code, then it just names them by the Id_number. Which is better but id prefer the Xpath text +id_number+.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `NoSuchElement` exception because you are using absolute `xPath` if `DOM` is dynamic there will be lot of chances for your script failure.

Always use reliable `xPath`

**xPath:** `//a//div[@class='flex-1 ellipsis padding-xs-right']`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the snapshot that you've shared, I believe you can use the below xpath

```
//a[contains(@href,'#resources/details/')]//div[contains(@class,'ellipsis')]
```

Also, before using this `xpath` check in Dev tools that we have `1/1` matching nodes.

Use it like this :

```
filename_first = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'#resources/details/')]//div[contains(@class,'ellipsis')]").text
print(filename_first)
```

one you get the desired output with the above code, we can replace it regex to get what you actually looking for.

Comment: Thanks! I did all that, and ran it in debugger, and it has filename_first as an empty string - I think thats because it says 1/23 matching nodes

Comment: Is it possible to share page URL ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Its a private website. but I can send snips of the HTML

Comment: Sure, please share addition info.

Comment: Thanks! Im not sure how to copy the next, so heres a screen shot. the black text at the very bottom is what i want to appear in the file name  https://ibb.co/6gzKZxQ

Comment: Im not sure - what would i search for in the html?

Comment: Just do ctrl + F from where you took the screenshot.

Comment: Sorry - it wasnt working because I may have sent you a file path too far: this may be more helpful https://ibb.co/Hr3LCmm

Comment: Press F12 in Chrome -> go to element section -> do a CTRL  + F -> then paste this `//a[contains(@href,'#resources/details/')]//div[contains(@class,'ellipsis')]` and see if your desired element is getting highlighted or not. if it is getting highlighted then on the extreme right, you would see a 1/1 or 1/2 something like that, take a snap and show me

Comment: https://ibb.co/nBjzp8g It comes up 23 times - for the 23 files - i want to extract that text, but i cant find the unique element designation

Comment: You can try xpath indexing `(//a[contains(@href,'#resources/details/')]//div[contains(@class,'ellipsis')])[23]` or [23] can be [1] or [2], check for which number it shows 1/1.

Comment: thanks! Do you have a recommendation on how to make the index number iterate in the for loop so it updates the file name accordingly?

Comment: Just put {} inside square bracket with iterator number, like if i is your iterator reference then it would be something like [{i}] instead of [23] for the above example.